# Vorticity in an irrotational flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

My understanding is that if vorticity is zero, then the flow is irrotational. Does that mean we can never have nonzero vorticity in an irrotational flow? If not, how can we have vorticity in an irrotational flow?

Comment: By definition it’s always zero. Perhaps you meant circulation which can be non-zero despite the irrotational condition.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. I am talking about vorticity

Comment: We cannot have nonzero vorticity in an [irrotational aka potential flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow). You may however look at the circulation of an [irrotational vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity).

Answer (score 0):

Many flows of engineering interest are broadly defined irrotational flows, but they are not properly. In flows like external flows around an airplane or a wing at low angle of incidence at high Reynolds number, **vorticity is confined in very thin layers** close to the body, namely the **boundary layer**, and thin "free" rotational regions, namely **the wakes**. In the rest of the domain, the flow can be treated as irritational.

Many models for these flows treat the rotational regions as infinitely thin *singularities*, that can be modelled as "cuts" in the irrotational domain.

Non-zero circulation in "irrotational" flows can exist because of these infinitely thin rotational regions in the domain, that cuts the domain.

Among these theories and methods:

- thin airfoil theory,
- Plant-Glauert theory for finite wing
- Hess-Smith method,
- panel methods and other boundary element formulations of the problem.